# Dir generates compile error looping through .msg files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a folder of email files from which I'm trying to extract sender details using `Dir`. I need help in determining why the following code doesn't compile.

```
Sub UpdateReturns()
    Dim fso As Object, fld As Object, olApp As Object, MailFile As Object, MsgDetail As Object
    Dim stSearch As String, stPath As String, stFile As String, EmailFrom As String

    stPath = "C:\010. Working Docs"
    stSearch = "Approve"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(stPath)
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    MailFile = Dir(stPath & "\*.msg")
    Do While MailFile <> ""
        Set MailFile = olApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(MailFile)
        Set MsgDetail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        EmailFrom = MsgDetail.SenderEmailAddress
        Sheets("Settings").Cells(41, 4).Value = EmailFrom
        'need to insert standard code to itterate down the list
        'and match sender names to recipient names and votes ("Approve") etc
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to use `MailFile` as both a `String` - in `MailFile = Dir...`, and as an `Object` - in `Set MailFile = ....`. Add a new variable for the first perhaps.

Comment: Yeah i tried that after i posted this, but i then get an error on the MsgDetail line saying "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: That's because you need to use `olApp`. `Application` refers to the *Excel* application.

Comment: And you never do anything with the message returned by OpenSharedItem - you always use the message from ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working a way around it. I was just spinning my wheels with the outlook controls and I decided to work with something I know better, end result was i set it up to read from a save folder where the files are saved as text files, and i have a formula where the contents of the searched files drop to match them against sent emails.

```
Sub UpdateReturns()
    Dim stPath As String, mailfile As String, Fname As String, Ename As String
    Dim fso As Object, fld As Object
    Dim i As Integer, count As Integer
    Const strSearch = "From:"
    stPath = "C:\010. Working Docs"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(stPath)

    mailfile = Dir(stPath & "\Approve*.txt")
    count = 0
    Do While mailfile <> ""
        count = count + 1
        mailfile = Dir()
    Loop
    i = 0
    mailfile = Dir(stPath & "\Approve*.txt")
    Do While count >= 1
        Open mailfile For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
            If InStr(textline, "From:") > 0 Then
                    Fname = mailfile
                    Ename = textline
            End If
        Loop
        Close #1
        Range("C" & (40 + count)).Value = Fname
        Range("D" & (40 + count)).Value = Ename
        mailfile = Dir()
        count = count - 1
     Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dir returns a string that represents the file name.

```
Sub UpdateReturns()

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim olApp As Object

    Dim MailFile As Object
    Dim MailFileStr As String
    Dim MailPathFileStr As String

    Dim stPath As String
    Dim EmailFrom As String

    stPath = "C:\010. Working Docs"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(stPath)

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    MailFileStr = Dir(stPath & "\*.msg")

    ' file name only, no path
    Debug.Print "MailFileStr: " & MailFileStr

    Do While MailFileStr <> ""

        ' path and file
        MailPathFileStr = stPath & "\" & MailFileStr
        Debug.Print vbCr & "MailPathFileStr: " & MailPathFileStr
        Set MailFile = olApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(MailPathFileStr)

        EmailFrom = MailFile.SenderEmailAddress
        Debug.Print "EmailFrom: " & EmailFrom

        Set MailFile = Nothing

        MailFileStr = Dir    ' Get next entry.

    Loop

End Sub
```